# delete uploaded image

Tags: javascript, jquery

i would like to know how i can make red "X" appear each time an Image appears. The red "X" is for deleting the image that the user chooses their will be a red X on each image. right now the X is just sitting on top of the container and it only shows one time if i click on the X all the images disappear and i don't whant that i want to delete individual images. how can i make this possible? Here is what i have.

```
    <div id="fotos" class="bananas"><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div>



<script>
$(".container5").on("dblclick", ".imgKLIK5", function () {

    var self = $(this);

    $(self).remove();
    $('#file1').val("");
});

var $btn = $("#imgdisplay");
$btn.click(function () {
    $("#fotos img:last-child").remove()
    $btn.hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your current remove implementation, goes 1 step back `parent()`, finds all `div` and removes them. So you can either have an extra div around this element to continue using this  or update the code to not step backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have wrapped your `div.bananas` inside a parent `div` with class `wrapper` you can use `.closest('.wrapper')` instead of `.parent().find()`.

```js
$('.bananas').click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest(".wrapper").remove();
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="fotos" class="bananas">X
    <img class="modal-content" src="http://assets.barcroftmedia.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets/images/recent-images-11.jpg" id="imgdisplay" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="fotos1" class="bananas">X
    <img class="modal-content" src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03598/lightning-10_3598416k.jpg" id="imgdisplay1" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i appreciate your help but this is not working the way i was hoping. i was looking for something that showed the X every time i uploaded an image and for the X not to show until an upload happened.this is the image that is displayed when i upload an image   <img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /> thank you for all your help

Comment: You've to show more code on how you are uploading images. Also, your question title doesn't match at all with the description, to be frank. So please update your question with more detail and into the point.. :)

Comment: So, if am getting your question right, then you are adding extra images to the t-shirt [Max 3] and you want close `button` on each image added, and on click of that you want to remove `src` of image rather than whole `element`, so that new image can be added again?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what I mean